# install ZFTool with composer/missing socket transport "ssl"

Tags: php, zend-framework

I want to start to learn Zend, but can't get the composer to install zftool. Trying to use composer to install zftool as explained [at ZF](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zendtool.introduction.html)

```
 ./composer.phar require zendframework/zftool:dev-master
```

I get the following error message:

```
composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Installing zendframework/zend-math (2.2.1)
    Downloading: 100%         
    Downloading: 100%         
    Downloading: 100%         

    [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]                                                                              
  The "http://nodeload.github.com/zendframework/Component_ZendMath/zip/release-2.2.1" file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: Unable to find the socket transport "ssl" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?                                                                                        
    require [--dev] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--no-progress] [--no-update] [packages1] ... [packagesN]
```

I have to admin, I normally don't mess around with my php.ini, but as far as I understand I have to enable the ssl-extension in it.
Opening the 5.4.10 php.ini of MAMP, there is nothing to uncomment, to enable the extension. Simply adding the line

```
extension=php_openssl.so
```

won't help. Anyone knows what to do?

Answer (score 2):

Okay, sorry to bother you, I finally found [something with google](http://www.ifusio.com/blog/install-open-ssl-extension-for-php-on-mac-osx). Apparently it's too easy. In fact, all you need to do is

```
sudo port install php5-openssl
```

Thanks anyway.